# Get number of documents returned from a query

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Can't seem to find an answer that answer my issue.

I have a series of MongoDB documents that contain version numbers, in terms of generational and incremental releases (e.g. 1.2, 1.4.2, etc.).

The code to search the DB is:

```
client = MongoClient("Localhost",27017)             # Set Mongo Client to local hose

db = client.Assignment                              # Set db as the DB required
collection = db.project                             # Set the collection to the collection required

Version = float(input("Enter version number:   "))

query = {"prod.v_num": Version}

Return = collection.find(query)

for doc in Return:
    print(doc["_id"], "¦", doc["prod"]["name"], "¦", doc["prod"]["v_num"], "¦",doc["owner"])
```

However, some of the time, there is no return from the search (i.e. there are no documents with the required version numbers).

How can I ascertain if there is no documents to match the return, and allow me to print out a warning message?

I tried this, but it didn't work

```py
if len(Return) == 0:
    print("No documents match your search").
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pymongo.cursor.Cursor` doesn't implement `__len__` method. That's why you get this error:

> TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

But it implements [`count`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/3.7.2/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count) method which *returns the number of documents in the results set for this query*. You can use it like this:

```
if Return.count() == 0:
    print("No documents match your search")
```

Also note that it was deprecated since Python3.7 version and you should use [`count_documents`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/3.7.2/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) query instead:

```
Return = collection.count_documents(query)
if Return == 0:
    print("No documents match your search")
```